# Dynamically storing/casting Objects in a heterogeneous array?

Tags: java, arrays, object, dynamic, casting

I’m storing different objects in an array in Java. I know to use a method for that array I need to cast it for its class.

Is there a way to perform the storing and recalls of the class type dynamically for casting it? I’m simply trying to change swing component bounds.

I know I can get it’s class and use conditionals to do the right casting, but if possible I’d like make it more dynamic.

Thanks!!

Comment: Could you add code of your past attempts to your question?

Comment: No, conditionals are the only way. Or store them in a separate container for each type.

Comment: Frasher, I’ve tried and deleted too many things to even post anything “close”. It’s not looking possible, thank though and thanks Andy!